# Using ReplaceAll on matrix to produce new list of complete matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

This seems like something simple but I can't find the answer.

If I have as input:

```
{{1, 2}, {3, d}} /. d -> {4, -4}
```

Mathematica outputs:

```
{{1, 2}, {3, {4, -4}}}
```

(which is logical as it simply replaces `d` with the list given)

What I'd like is the following output, i.e., a new list of complete 2x2 matrices:

```
{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {3, -4}}}
```

To give a bit more context, I have two lists of matrices that I'd like to multiply to give all the combinations, e.g.:

```
list1 = {A,B,C}
list2 = {D,E}
```

into

```
{A.D,A.E,B.D,B.E,C.D,C.E}
```

I already found this trick:

```
Dot @@@ Tuples[{list1, list2}]
```

But prior to multiplying the list I need to do a replace all as described above to produce the actual matrices to multiply together.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html):

```
Table[{{1, 2}, {3, d}}, {d, {4, -4}}]
(* {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {3, -4}}} *)
```

Comment: Knew it had to be simple, thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
rules =  List /@ Thread[d -> {4, -4}]
```

> {{d -> 4}, {d -> -4}}

```
{{1, 2}, {3, d}} /. rules
```

> {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {3, -4}}}

**Note:** With a list of rules `ReplaceAll` uses the first matching rule:

```
x /. {x -> 1, x -> a, x -> 2}
```

> 1

To apply each rule separately, you need to wrap each rule with `List`:

```
x /. {{x -> 1}, {x -> a}, {x -> 2}}
```

> {1, a, 2}